# After running a bunch of queries the table keeps crashing

Tags: php, mysql

Table 'geoPoint' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

I call this function with a file that has 500 lines
this results in 500 queries that get called in quick succession...

This may not be the most efficient, but why does it constantly crash the geopoint table??

```
CSVImport($table, $fields,$_FILES["file"["tmp_name"],$cardID,2);

function CSVImport($table, $fields, $file,$cardID,$intype) {
    if($file == null)
    {
        echo "Error No File";
         die('Cannot open uploaded file.');
    }
    $handle = fopen($file,'r');
    if(!$handle) die('Cannot open uploaded file.');

    $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
    copy($file, $tmpfname);
    $row_count = 0;
    $rows = array();

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row_count++;
        $itemcount = 0;

        $NAME = $data[0];
        $LAT = $data[1];
        echo "<td>{$LAT}</td>";
        $LON = $data[2];
        echo "<td>{$LON}</td>";
        $STREETNUM = $data[3];
        echo "<td>{$STREETNUM}</td>";
        $STREETNAME = $data[4];
        echo "<td>{$STREETNAME}</td>";
        $CITY = $data[5];
        echo "<td>{$CITY}</td>";
        $ZIP = $data[6];
        echo "<td>{$ZIP}</td>";
        $COUNTY = $data[7];
        echo "<td>{$COUNTY}</td>";
        $UUID = $data[8];
        echo "<td>{$GEOTYPE}</td>";
        $DATE = $data[9];
        echo "<td>{$DATE}</td>";
        $GARCOMUUID = $data[10];
        echo "<td>{$GARCOMUUID}</td>";
        $CITYUUID = $data[11];
        echo "<td>{$CITYUUID}</td>";
        $CITYSPECUUID = $data[12];
        $latRound = number_format((float)$LAT, 3, '.', '');
        $lonRound = number_format((float)$LON, 3, '.', '');
        number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');

        echo "<td>{$CITYSPECUUID}</td>";

        $custquery="SELECT * FROM `geoPoint` WHERE `lat` LIKE '%{$latRound}%' AND `lon` LIKE '%{$lonRound}%' AND `street_num` = {$STREETNUM}";

        $custre=mysql_query($custquery);
        if (!$custre) {    echo 'Could not run custre query: ' . mysql_error();    exit;    }
        $custarr = mysql_fetch_array($custre, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        if($custarr == null)
            $itemisnew = 0;
        else
        {
            $itemisnew = mysql_num_rows(custarr);
        }
        if($itemisnew == 0)
            echo "<td>NEW</td>";
        else if($itemisnew == 1)
            echo "<td>REPLACE</td>";
        else
            echo "<td>MULTIPLE!</td>";
    }

    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I can always repair the table through phpmyadmin

Comment: `SELECT` queries don't modify the table, I don't think they can cause damage. Are you sure this is the function where it's happening?

Comment: yeah - i run it, then crashes... :/

Comment: Maybe some other script is writing to the table at the same time, and it's damaging the table.

Comment: Have you checked for memory exhaustion?

Comment: can't be anything else... only one using during this test

Comment: how do i check for memory exhaustion?

Comment: so - doesn't actually look like the table is crashing... it just says it is, but if i go and run SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `db`  - nothing looks out of order...

Comment: by adding this to the while loop it works... if($row_count > 300)
     break;

Comment: seems like its around 800 queries consistently breaks it... 700 works every time, 800 tells me the table crashes

Answer (score 3):

A table crash is not something you can cause in PHP.  It's the result of either a hardware failure (bad memory or disk corruption), misconfiguration, or a bug in MySQL.

When the table crashes, does anything show up in MySQL's error log ?  If MySQL is set to use too much memory, it could be tripping Linux' out-of-memory handler, which would kill the MySQL process, leaving your table in a "dirty" state.  You might not notice since many distros' scripts will monitor and restart a crashed daemon automatically.  That would be my first guess.

Comment: Yep, and `mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'UPTIME';` should be a simple way to confirm that.  On a small system, MySQL can often recover so quickly that you may not notice... but if the uptime counter resets, that's a really good hint that this is what's happening.